# Ubuntu Root on ZFS

Tags: partitioning, root, raid, zfs

These questions are in regard to this article:
https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2020.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html

I intend to follow those instructions using an Ubuntu 21.10 64 bit installation ISO file.

I have two 2TB SSD, and two 12 TB HDD. My goal is to use ZFS to software RAID 1 mirror the two SSD, and also the two HDD together. Then to create in the RAIDed SSDs the boot, swap, root, and LVM write through cache, partitions. The /home directory is to be on the RAIDed HDD. Both SSD, and HDD, are to be encrypted.

In [Step 2.1](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2020.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html#step-2-disk-formatting) the variable "DISK" is set to a path to a disk hardware node. Farther on in these instructions the variables "DISK1", and "DISK2", are used and there is no instruction to set them to anything. Am I correct that in the case of two or more disks to be RAIDed, instead of the "DISK" variable being set, the variables "DISK1", "DISK2", "DISK3", etc, should be set instead, and each set to their respective hardware nodes?

In [Step 4.7](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2020.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html#step-4-system-configuration) the instruction is to execute the mkdosfs for each disk in the RAID array (DISK1, DISK2, DISK3, etc instead of just "DISK"). It says not do the same for the other commands below mkdosfs. But here there is an echo command that copies information for a disk into "/etc/ fstab" for the variable "DISK". Am I correct that actually, in the case of multiple disks, this echo command should also be executed for each of DISK1, DISK2, DISK3, etc ? And should this also be the case wherever else the variable name "DISK" appears?

In [Step 2.3](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2020.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html#step-2-disk-formatting) the first partition on the drive, which is partition number 5, starts at 24K. This 24K of disk space is not partitioned anywhere else in the instructions, and so this space is left unpartitioned. Why is this the case? Should a drive that is not to be booted from, and contains only data, also have its first 24K left unpartitioned? How is it to be determined that 24K is the right amount of disk space to leave free?

Comment: Sorry ... there's too many words that go nowhere. What is it that you're trying to do? Do you wish to install Ubuntu and have only a ZFS file system? 21.10 will do this out of the box. Do not use ZFS if you have a multi-boot environment, though, as ZFS practically demands the full disk to itself.

Comment: I intend to RAID two pairs of drives, and encrypt them. There will be no multi-boot. If I need to run an MS Windows only program I will run it in Crossover, and if that does not work, I will run it in Windows 10 running as a guest inside VirtualBox.

Comment: RAID0 or RAID1? Will this be a hardware RAID or a software RAID? Generally, I do not use RAID with ZFS unless there is a need to achieve very specific read speeds. ZFS pools are incredibly stable and, in the event of a hardware failure, ZFS replication has me (and my employer) covered. A new drive can be installed and resilvered in a matter of hours. How much RAM is on your machine? Depending on your goals with ZFS, you may need a good amount of overhead for buffers, which will come out of RAM well before it's flushed to disk ...

Comment: Software RAID 1 Mirror. The processor is AMD, and AMD RAID hardware is no good. The goal is not to have single point failure. RAM is 128 GiB.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: This installation will NOT be done remotely. It is being done using a USB drive with the installation ISO written on it, keyboard, and mouse, plugged directly in to the computer the installation is to be done on.

I have not yet attempted this installation. When I read the procedure I linked to these questions arose. I need them answered before I attempt the installation.

Answer (score 0):

First, beware the boot/EFI partition is not mirroed (unless you have hardware raid), so, only one of the boot devices will be used (you may replicate the boot/EFI partition to the other SSD).

My suggestion is to create two partitions on the SSDs (beside the boot/EFI partition, the bpool and the rpool): the cache and the zil vdevs for the data (/home directory) pool, `dpool`, created on the top of the HDDs-based vdevs, created as whole device, then, add the cache/log from the SSDs:

```
zpool create dpool mirror hdd1 hdd2
zpool add dpool cache mirror ssd1p4 ssd2p5
zpool add dpool log mirror ssd1p4 ssd2p5
```

Then, use this pool for your data (setting `mountpoint=/home`), deleting any dataset that uses this mountpoint if necessary, prevous backups.